# How to search variety of form controls for completeness on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, loops

Thank you for viewing this post.  I am just a beginner with C# and WPF and my little project is rapidly turning into a hot mess.  I have a WPF form I am making for scheduling purposes.  Currently I am trying to clean up some code I have cobbled together.  It sort of works the way I want but it isn't quite there yet.  I have a mix of combobox, textbox, date and time pickers, some controls are hidden until selection  dictates otherwise. Where I am currently is the click button control that will eventually push the data to where I need it.  What I would like the click button to do initally is this :

Look at all the controls, find the ones that are currently visible.  Of the visible controls, check that they are not empty/null.  If the control is empty/null, highlight the field and display a single message saying "Required data missing".

I have looked around on the web and I feel that looping through these would be a far superior way to go, however, my general lack of understanding has prevented me from making this work.  As I mentioned earlier, I have a mix of control types, some of which are from the Xceed WPF toolkit.

Here is what I came up with:

```
private void Submit_BT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PatientName.Text))
        {
            PatientName.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            PatientName.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MRN.Text))
        {
            MRN.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            MRN.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Procedure.Text))
        {
            Procedure.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Procedure.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Levels.Text))
        {
            Levels.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Levels.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Modality_Select.Text))
        {
            Modality_Select.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Modality_Select.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Insurance.Text))
        {
            Insurance.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Insurance.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sched.Text))
        {
            Sched.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Sched.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(OR_Num.Text))
        {
            OR_Num.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            OR_Num.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sched_Date.Text))
        {
            Sched_Date.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Sched_Date.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }


        if (Start_Time.Value == null)
        {
            Start_Time.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Start_Time.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Combobox1.Text))
        {
            Combobox1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Combobox1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (End_Time.Value == null)
        {
            End_Time.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            End_Time.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Combobox2.Text))
        {
            Combobox2.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
        }
        else
        {
            Combobox2.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }

        if (EMG_Type.IsVisible)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EMG_Type.Text))
            {
                EMG_Type.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
            }
            else
            {
                EMG_Type.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            }

            if (Other_TB.IsVisible)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Other_TB.Text))
                {
                    Other_TB.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightPink;
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You are missing required data");
                }
                else
                {
                    Other_TB.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I get this to work by looping through the controls, show only 1 error message if applicable, yet highlight each control that is empty/null?

Thank you for any help you may lend.

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

hi i personally do not support this type of approach for validation in WPF, in WPF we can do this by using IDataErrorInfo.

```
    public string Error
    {
       get
          {
               return null;
          }
    }


    public string this[string name]
    {
        ValidateProperty(name);
    }

public override void ValidateProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        Tracer.LogValidation("INotifyDataErrorInfo.ValidateProperty called. Validating " + propertyName);
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "x":
                {
                    ValidateNonNegative(x, "x");
                    ValidateMandatory(x, "x");
                }
            break;

        case "y":
            {
                ValidateNonNegative(y, "y");
                ValidateMandatory(y, "y");
            }
            break;
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
    {
        Tracer.LogValidation("No cross-property validation errors.");
    }
  }
```

[Validation-in-WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863291/Validation-in-WPF)

[Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation)

[data-validation-in-3-5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'll do some more reading on this and see where it takes me.